# Spring Integration JMS Outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Please let me know if we can configure int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter to return a value to the caller (can be a dummy value). I have header enricher, which internally calls the jms outbound adapter to send a message to active mq. I am able to send the message to MQ but since there is no return from jms adapter, the steps after header enricher is not getting executed. Below is my configuration

```
    <int:header-enricher input-channel="inputMessageChannel"  output-channel="messagePublishChannel">
        <int:header name="message_success" expression="@gateway.exchange(#root).payload" />
 </int:header-enricher>



  <int:header-value-router  input-channel="messagePublishChannel" header-name="mqstatus">
        <int:mapping value="success" channel="responseCreatorChannel" />
        <int:mapping value="failure" channel="errorChannel" />
  </int:header-value-router>

<int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="getQdetails" />
<int:chain input-channel="getQdetails">
    <int:service-activator  ref="rdrBusinessRulesValidationService" method="transform" />
    <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" result-transformer="messageResultTransformer">
    </int-xml:marshalling-transformer>
     <int:header-value-router header-name="region">
        <int:mapping value="USA" channel="region1Channel" />
        <int:mapping value="PRI" channel="region2Channel" />
     </int:header-value-router>
</int:chain>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="region1Channel" connection-factory="activeMqconnectionFactory"  destination="region1Destination">
    <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="@service.setSuccess(#root)" />
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="@service.setFailure(#root)" />
        </bean>

    </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain> 

</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return anything from any Outbound Channel Adapter. They fully aren't intended for such a behavior.

You just need to configure [`PublishSubscribeChannel`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel) as an `output-channel` for your Header Enricher and make two subscribers for that. The first one is still your JMS Outbound Channel Adapter. Another one that which you would like to perform after sending JMS message.

Note: the same message will be send to both subscribers.

**UPDATE**

OK. Thank you for sharing the config. Now I see your point.

Your use-case is to enrich a message with the header as a result of the `<gateway>` invocation. But since the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` is one-way component you don't receive from there any reply.

I'm not sure what you are going to represent as a `message_success` header, but I see that you can make `getQdetails` as a `<publish-subscribe-channel>` and add the second subscriber (alongside with that `<chain>`) as:

```
<bridge input-channel="getQdetails" order="2"/>
```

And the same message as an input for the top-level `header-enricher` will be sent you back to the `message_success` header.

**UPDATE2**

According to your requirements with the `true/false` value for the top-level header I can suggest something like this instead of `publish-subscriber-channel`:

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="region1Channel" connection-factory="activeMqconnectionFactory"  destination="region1Destination">
    <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="T(Boolean).TRUE" />
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="T(Boolean).FALSE" />
            <property name="successChannel" ref="toReplySuccess" />
            <property name="failureChannel" ref="toReplyFailure" />
            <property name="trapException" ref="true" />
        </bean>
    </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain> 
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

<chain input-channel="toReplySuccess">
    <transformer 
       expression="T(org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder).createMessage(payload, inputMessage.headers)" />
    <bridge />
</chain>


<chain input-channel="toReplyFailure">
    <transformer 
       expression="T(org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder).createMessage(payload.evaluationResult, payload.failedMessage.headers)" />
    <bridge />
</chain>
```

So, what I do here:

1. Instead of your service to enrich header in the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` I simply return `boolean` according the `success/failure` state.
2. In success case the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` sends an `AdviceMessage` without the copy of `requestMessage` headers.
3. So, that smart `<chain input-channel="toReplySuccess">` tries to restore `requestMessage` headers to get access to the standard `replyChannel` mechanism.
4. We build here a new message with the `Boolean.TRUE` `payload` and headers from that `inputMessage` property of the incoming `AdviceMessage`.
5. We use here further a `<bridge>` to really send reply to your top-level `header-enricher`
6. For the `toReplyFailure` we have similar "smart" `<chain>` but with a bit different `transformer`, just because on failure the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` sends an `ErrorMessage` with the `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException` as a `payload`, where we can find our `requestMessage` with desired `replyChannel` header in the `failedMessage` property of the exception.

Hope that is clear.

**UPDATE3**

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="inputMessageChannel"  output-channel="messagePublishChannel">
        <int:header name="message_success" expression="@gateway.exchange(#root).payload" />
    </int:header-enricher>



    <int:header-value-router  input-channel="messagePublishChannel" header-name="mqstatus">
        <int:mapping value="success" channel="responseCreatorChannel" />
        <int:mapping value="failure" channel="errorChannel" />
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="getQdetails" />
    <int:chain input-channel="getQdetails">
        <int:service-activator  ref="rdrBusinessRulesValidationService" method="transform" />
        <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" result-transformer="messageResultTransformer">
        </int-xml:marshalling-transformer>
        <int:header-value-router header-name="region">
            <int:mapping value="USA" channel="region1Channel" />
            <int:mapping value="PRI" channel="region2Channel" />
        </int:header-value-router>
    </int:chain>

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="region1Channel" connection-factory="activeMqconnectionFactory"  destination="region1Destination">
        <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="T(Boolean).TRUE" />
                <property name="onFailureExpression" value="T(Boolean).FALSE" />
                <property name="successChannel" ref="toReplySuccess" />
                <property name="failureChannel" ref="toReplyFailure" />
                <property name="trapException" ref="true" />
            </bean>
        </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

        <int:transformer input-channel="toReplySuccess" output-channel="toReplyChannel"
                expression="T(org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder)
                .createMessage(payload, inputMessage.headers)" />



    <int:transformer input-channel="toReplyFailure"
                expression="T(org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder)
                .createMessage(payload.evaluationResult, payload.failedMessage.headers)" />

    <int:bridge input-channel="toReplyChannel"/>
```

Comment: Below is my configuration<int:header-enricher input-channel="inputMessageChannel"  output-channel="messagePublishChannel">
    <int:header name="message_success" expression="@gateway.exchange(#root).payload" />
  </int:header-enricher>
  

  
   <int:header-value-router  input-channel="messagePublishChannel" header-name="mqstatus">
    <int:mapping value="success" channel="responseCreatorChannel" />
      <int:mapping value="failure" channel="errorChannel" />
   </int:header-value-router>

Comment: <int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="getQdetails" />
    <int:chain input-channel="getQdetails">
     <int:service-activator  ref="rdrBusinessRulesValidationService" method="transform" />
     <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" result-transformer="messageResultTransformer">
  </int-xml:marshalling-transformer>
   <int:header-value-router header-name="region">
    <int:mapping value="USA" channel="region1Channel" />
      <int:mapping value="PRI" channel="region2Channel" />
   </int:header-value-router>
    </int:chain>

Comment: <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="region1Channel" connection-factory="activeMqconnectionFactory"  destination="region1Destination">
  <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="@service.setSuccess(#root)" />
    <property name="onFailureExpression" value="@service.setFailure(#root)" />
   </bean>
   
  </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain> 
   
 </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: Please let me know which channel should be pub sub in this case

Comment: No, that's bad. It isn't readable. Please, use an edit to your question with code style formatting

Comment: Yes.. worked like a charm.. But one more question regarding this configuration, @service.setSuccess(#root) is updating the header "mqstatus" to success, which will be used subsequently by the header value router to route the message to responseCreatorChannel.  But somehow the header is getting lost and header router is not able not route it. Also regarding the header message_status, It is not used in the subsequent flow. As I dont want to disturb the original payload, so i followed this approach. Please let me know if there is a better approach

Comment: Hi Artem, please let me know your thoughts

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I have missed your comment, even if I subscribed to that question back.

Comment: Well, that won't work that way because there are nothing after that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and you just end up there on the one-way Outbound Channel Adapter. You should move such a logic to the second subscriber, e.g. `header-enricher` instead of that `bridge`. Although you even can send the expression evaluation result to some channel as well, e.g. to similar `<bridge>`. See `successChannel` and `failureChannel` option of `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

Comment: Hi Artem, could you please provide a sample configuration of such a header enricher, which can be used, instead of bridge

Comment: Well, see an UPDATE2 in my answer.

Comment: Hi Artem. Thank you very much for the details. But can we give "bridge" inside "chain"? It is giving error for me. I am using SI  4.0.5

Comment: Ha! Funny, we really can't do that even with the latest version :-). So, you should move the `<bridge>` outside of the `<chain>`. And meanwhile I'd like to ask you for the JIRA about the `<bridge>` in the `<chain>`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Comment: so I think toReplySuccess and toReplyFailure should be pub sub in this case

Comment: No, you should just have an `output-channel` on both `<transformer>`s to the same channel with `<bridge>` and remove those `<chain>`s already.

Comment: It seems like the message sent to successChannel is an instance of GenericMessage, not AdviceMessage, so the expression inputMessage.headers is failing. Something wrong I am doing?

Comment: You might have something else what send that message. It can't be `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/handler/advice/ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java#L166-L168

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107996/discussion-between-anil-bhaskaran-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Hi Artem, Regarding the issue of generic message, i will do some more debugging. Just to understand it clearly, output channel of the transformer should be getQdetails, for which we already have a chain and bridge as suscribers (referring to the bridge solution provided by you). ?

Comment: No, of course, no. The `getQdetails` is a channel from the gateway and input for your `chain`. We don't need that "old" `bridge` anymore, since we are moving to the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` more smart solution.

Comment: Sorry.. I am stil not able to understand how to connect the transformer and bridge

Comment: See an UPDATE3 in my answer. That is how I imaging your solution.

Comment: Hi Artem, I found the RC for the issue related to generic message. My configuration contains <int:message-history/>. So the  method  AbstractMessageChannel.send(Message<?> message, long timeout) has a logic which returns Generic message, if the history is enabled.    if (this.shouldTrack) {
 message = MessageHistory.write(message, this,      this.getMessageBuilderFactory());
  }. This is causing the issue. Is it a bug?

Comment: Looks that is a fully different story. Don't see reason to discuss it here.

Comment: I was referring to the comment on April 1 2016 20:23 and April 1 2016 20:26. Please let me know if you want me to open a separate discussion for that

Comment: Oh! Yes. That definitely looks like a bug in. Please, raise a JIRA issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT). The `MessageHistory` must retain the message type.

Comment: ok.. Was actually trying to do  that...  What about the comment  Apr 1 at 18:34

Comment: Thank you... Accepting the solution... :)